# Is it better to create a function or a variable for current_theme_supports?

Tags: php, add-theme-support, coding-standards

Well I just asking myself this, there are two ways I could implement this. What would be a better fit to coding standards?
Or is this just a a matter of personal like?

**And what about php and memory, assuming this would be way more complicated and executed very often. Would it cost more memory to create a function or a variable?**

Solution 1:

```
function stuff(){

    [...]

    $fluid = ( current_theme_supports('greatness') ) ? '-greatness' : '';

    $output = '<div class="box' . $fluid . '">';

    [...]

}
```

Solution 2:

```
function stuff_alternative(){

    [...]        

    $output = '<div class="box' . bootgen_is_great() . '">';

    [...]

}

function bootgen_is_great(){

    if ( current_theme_supports( 'greatness' ) )
        return '-greatness';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory is not the issue here. There are no complex operations, and the difference will be almost unmeasurable.

What matters is readability: If your `stuff` function is rather short (less than eight functional steps) and you use the check just once – keep the check in it.
But if you need the support check in different functions separate it.

I'd rather **optimize the names**: `greatness` is not very descriptive, and while I like fluid layouts – they are not a synonym for great layouts. :)
Also, it is a custom name, so [prefix it](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/) to avoid collisions with plugins and to tell the uninformed reader (you, one year later) that it *is* something custom.

Suggestion for a theme named *wpse51275:*

```
function wpse51275_box()
{
    // some awesome code …

    $box_class = 'box';
    current_theme_supports( 'wpse51275_fluid_layout' ) and $box_class .= '-fluid';

    $output = "<div class='$box_class'>";

    // more awesome code …
}
```

Comment: of course in this example memory is not an issue! It was a general question. Lets pretend the functions are way more complex and executed million times. I am php noob but my guess would be that a function costs more memory.

Comment: And I used names like greatness only for stack overflow because its nobodys business what I am working on, of course this is not called greatness in my code. I am not familiar with this kind of `and` useage without any if of brackets. I don't really like it but I think its maybe a good Idea to put the whole class in a variable in the first place.